# Не могу понять функции С++

Tags: c++

https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-functions/#more - здесь читаю, не могу понять функции с возвращением значения....это фейл госпада

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string check_pass (string password)
{
    string valid_pass = "qwerty123";
    string error_message;
    if (password == valid_pass) {
        error_message = "Доступ разрешен.";
    } else {
        error_message = "Неверный пароль!";
    }
    return error_message;
}

int main()
{    
    string user_pass;
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    getline (cin, user_pass);
    string error_msg = check_pass (user_pass);
    cout << error_msg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу разобраться, что происходит

@Harry
Более чем, а вот здесь есть вопросы т.к. писал всегда return 0; // Возвращаем сообщение - return error_message; // этот момент не понял, для чего.. - // error_msg было error_message тоже непонятно –

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Уточните свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string check_pass (string password)
{
   // Строка с правильным паролем 
   string valid_pass = "qwerty123";
   // Сообщение, которое вернет функция
    string error_message;
   // Если переданный пароль совпадает с "правильным"
    if (password == valid_pass) {
   // то доступ разрешен
        error_message = "Доступ разрешен.";
    } else {
   // Иначе - нет
        error_message = "Неверный пароль!";
    }
   // Возвращаем сообщение
    return error_message;
}

int main()
{    
    string user_pass;
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    // Считываем пароль
    getline (cin, user_pass);
    // Передаем в функцию
    string error_msg = check_pass (user_pass);
    // Выводим возвращенное ею значение
    cout << error_msg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Так понятно?

Comment: Более чем, а вот здесь есть вопросы т.к. писал всегда return 0; // Возвращаем сообщение - return error_message; // этот момент не понял, для чего.. - // error_msg было error_message тоже непонятно –

Comment: Ну вы просто возвращаете из функции не целое число, а объект типа `string`. Для чего? Ну, так автор задумал :) В `main` это строка просто выводится на экран...